# After changing the reference point in SFML the coordinate system, the coordinates are calculated incorrectly

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

By default SFML originates from the top left corner window, I put the origin of the coordinate axis in the center of the bottom of the window. The x axis has a range (-400; 400), this is normal. But I have problems with the y-axis, when lifting the object up, the position value falls, the top point is -600, not 600. I want that at rising to the top point, value increased, instead of decreased as now.

The top coordinate of the window is -600, and 600 was expected

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

int speed = 1000;

int main()
{
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), L"Test");
RectangleShape rect;
View view;
view.setCenter(0, -300); //!!!
view.setSize(800, 600);
window.setView(view);
rect.setFillColor(Color::Green);
rect.setSize(Vector2f(50, 50));
rect.setPosition(Vector2f(0, 600));
rect.setOrigin(25, 25);
Clock clock;
while (window.isOpen())
{
    float time = clock.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();
    clock.restart();
    time /= speed; //1000
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up))
        rect.move(0, -0.1*time);
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down))
        rect.move(0, 0.1*time);
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left))
        rect.move(-0.1*time, 0);
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right))
        rect.move(0.1*time, 0);
    cout << rect.getPosition().x << " " << rect.getPosition().y << "\n";
    window.clear(Color::White);
    window.draw(rect);
    window.display();
}
return 0;
}
```

The top coordinate of the window is -600, and 600 was expected.

[image: Start point]
[image: Wrong coordinates on the y-axis, expected 200]

Comment: You misunderstand your code

Comment: This a bad. Very bad.

Answer (score 1):

**You're messing with the coordinates**. I add this image to ilustrate:

[image]

The black background window is your original window. You need to imagine your window as that, a window which **shows a view of a infinite plane**. It starts showing points from (0,0) (top-left corner) to (800,600) (bottom-right corner).

When you create a window, it has to have a view. By default, the view of your window is a view **centered** at (400,300), with the **size** of the whole window (blue rectangle).

First thing you do is:

```
view.setCenter(0, -300); //!!!
view.setSize(800, 600);
window.setView(view);
```

So you're now *moving* the view of your window (green rectangle). The center of that view is now on (0,-300), with the size of the original window.

Then you draw your square:

```
rect.setSize(Vector2f(50, 50));
rect.setPosition(Vector2f(0, 600));
rect.setOrigin(25, 25);
```

This is a square which center point will be (0,600) (bottom-left corner of the original window).

As you're viewing a section of the plane above the line `x=0`, you will need to move your square (almost) 600 units up in order to view it, i.e. up to (0,0). That's in fact what's happening.

Comment: In fact, you're not changing the reference of the coordinate system. You're only moving the view, so, the point (0,600) still at (0,600), but you can't see it because you're looking upwards.

Comment: Can I fix my problem?

Comment: Maybe I should have started talking about SFML coordinates. Top-left corner is, by default (0,0) and note that bottom-right corner is at (800,**600**) in your case. With *y* coordinate positive. Going **downwards** implies **increase** *y* values.